# Restore Ubuntu Server to Previous State

Tags: server, backup, restore, vps, systemback

I am using ubuntu desktop from quite some time but I am a little new to ubuntu server. I purchased a VPS, install and configure different programs and now it is in running state. I want to make some changes but before making those changes I want to make a restore point, so if something goes wrong I can go back to a working state.

In Ubuntu desktop version, I use [systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback) for this purpose. I know systemback have a CLI version, and I found [this tutorial](https://www.ostechnix.com/systemback-restore-ubuntu-desktop-and-server-to-previous-state/) for server backup & restore but unfortunately it is not working.

I will be grateful if someone can share an alternative way of doing this. Can we do this with timeshift? any other recommended method? step by step tutorial will be greatly appreciated.

P.S: I have ubuntu 16.04 as my server os and using VPS for a Magento shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Time Shift for this purpose. It has GUI as well as CLI that you can use for both Ubuntu server and Desktop editions.

`sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timeshift`